# split multiple urls using urlparse in python

Tags: python, urlparse

I have a string with multiple urls extracted using `BeautifulSoup` and I want to split all of these urls to extract dates and year (the urls have dates and year in them).

```
print(dat)
http://www.foo.com/2016/01/0124
http://www.foo.com/2016/02/0122
http://www.foo.com/2016/02/0426
http://www.foo.com/2016/03/0129
.
.
```

I tried the following but it only retrieves the first:

```
import urlparse
parsed = urlparse(dat)
path = parsed[2] #defining after www.foo.com/
pathlist = path.split("/")

['', '2016', '01', '0124']
```

So I am only getting result for the first element of the string.
How can I retrieve these parses for all of the urls, and store them so I can extract information? I would like know how many of the links there are for year and month.

Also strangely after doing this, when I do `print(dat)` I only get the first element `http://www.foo.com/2016/01/0124`, it seems that `urlparse` is not working for multiple urls.

Comment: Euh can't you use a regex, that looks like an appropriate tool here. Furthermore how are the urls joined in the first place?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem They were extracted using Beautifulsoup and then converted to string by using str()

Comment: but they are sepated by new lines? In that case you can use a `for` loop over your script.

Comment: can you give the type of `dat` (what is the result of `type(dat)`)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes they are separated by new lines, could you help me with using the for loop? I'm new to python.

Comment: if you use `find_all` then use `for` loop.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem type 'str'

Comment: why do you convert to `str()` ?  Use `for item in find_all(..); do_somethind(item)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, it looks like you have a list of URLs separated by new lines. In that case you can use a `for` loop to iterate over them:

```
list_pathlist = []
for url in dat.split('\n'):
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    path = parsed[2] #defining after www.foo.com/
    pathlist = path.split("/")
    list_pathlist.append(pathlist)
```

In which case I suspect the result (`list_pathlist`) will be something like:

```
[['', '2016', '01', '0124'],['', '2016', '02', '1222'],...]
```

so a *list of lists*.

Or you can put it into a nice *one-liner* using *list-comprehension*:

```
list_pathlist = [urlparse(url)[2].split('/') for url in dat.split('\n')]
```